# Calculation number of packages needed to make a recipe

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Good afternoon,

I've created this measure in Power bi to calculate the total cost of a recipe based on the number of packages that need to be bought:

```
Kostprijs per aangekochte verpakking Hoogste Prijs =
SUMX (
    'Ingrediënten';
    'Ingrediënten'[Verpakking Gewicht Duurste Prijs]
        * IF (
            ( 'Ingrediënten'[Hoeveelheid] / 4 )
                * SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Slicer Aantal Personen'[Aantal Personen] )
                <= 'Ingrediënten'[Verpakking Gewicht Duurste Prijs];
            1;
            2
        )
        * RELATED ( 'Product'[Duurste Prijs] )
)
```

However, in this calculation it says, that I need or 1 or 2 packages, but sometimes I need 3 or 4 packaged.
The number of packages needed depends on the number op people in the recipe. The calculation I have in mind is : 
Ingredienten[Verpakking Gewicht Duurste Prijs]/Ingrediënten[Hoeveelheid/'Slicer aantal Personen'[Aantal Personen]. 
Also it is important that this number is rounded up (no decimals)
But I can't figure out how I can get this calculation in the measure above.

Thanks for your help.

Kind regards,

Comment: If ('Slicer Aantal Personen'[Aantal Personen])<='Ingrediënten'[Verpakking Gewicht Duurste Prijs] is true, then the number of packages should be one. In the other case: it should be calculated as follows (Ingrediënten[Hoeveelheid]/Ingrediënten[VerpakkingGewicht Duurste Prijs] and this value should be rounded up

Comment: Could you please provide a table with a simple but representative example and the expected solution given that input data?

Comment: @Seymour : you can find the pbix-file using the following link (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuaqHTxLCZ_h1Xk2Xd40k9_iuE5S?e=6eNmQG). 
I also created an excel file with an example of the calculation : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuaqHTxLCZ_h1X3IS-Z4NCzj1jtv?e=Y0VZbS

Comment: I've created an excel sheeft based on Verpakking Hoogste Prijs. It includes the results that the meausure "Kostprijs Per aangekochte Verpakking Hoogste Prijs" should produce.

 
Link to the excel file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuaqHTxLCZ_h1jpRcr4IUX53wYDK?e=oocKku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
sumx('Ingrediënten';
    (
        'Ingrediënten'[Verpakking Gewicht Duurste Prijs]
            * if (
               ('Ingrediënten'[Hoeveelheid]/4) 
                    * SELECTEDVALUE('Slicer Aantal Personen'[Aantal Personen]) > 'Ingrediënten'[Verpakking Gewicht Duurste Prijs];( ROUNDUP (
                    DIVIDE (
                       (('Ingrediënten'[Hoeveelheid]/4)*SELECTEDVALUE('Slicer Aantal Personen'[Aantal Personen]));
                        'Ingrediënten'[Verpakking Gewicht Duurste Prijs]
                    );0));1)
                        * RELATED ( 'Product'[Duurste Prijs] )

```
        )
)
```